# Summary + ajax paging on ExtJS.Grid

Tags: ajax, extjs, extjs4, paging, summary

I have a grid with data similar to http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.1/examples/grid/array-grid.html, but using paged proxy similar to http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.1/examples/grid/paging.html.

I need to add a summary similar to http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.1/examples/grid/group-summary-grid.html, only 1 at the bottom of the grid. It must sum all data, not only data from current page.

I can make the DB query, no need Ext to sum the values. But how will I send the summary data to Ext.store and from store to grid?

Comment: Maybe it will be easier to add additional field to model that is bind to store(for example summary). Fill that field from json and show somewhere in grid ?

Comment: Maybe, have you seen an example that I could use? Still, I need the visual effect of ExtJs.Grid summary, it can't just be another grid row.

Comment: @Hikari You can always use the SummaryRenderer property of Column from where you can return custom values and apply formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Handle this as example how you could implement.

This is how it looks like(of course it will be different data but you see the point):
[image]

Lets see example of **json**(how it could be and how i understand your problem):

```
{
   "stats":[
      {
         "name":"Amount summary",
         "value":"2300"
      },
      {
         "name":"Mortgage",
         "value":"1100"
      }
   ],
   "success":true,
   "totalCount":2,
   "items":[
      {
         "Amount":"1000",
         "Delta":"3",
         "Mortgage":"500"
      },{
         "Amount":"1300",
         "Delta":"4",
         "Mortgage":"600"
      }
   ]
}
```

**Model**:

```
Ext.define('Application.model.MyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{
        name: 'Amount',
        type: 'string'
    },{
        name: 'Delta',
        type: 'string'
    },{
        name: 'Mortgage',
        type: 'string'
    }]
});
```

**Store**:

```
var writer = new Ext.data.JsonWriter({
    type: 'json',
    encode: false,
    listful: true,
    writeAllFields: true,
    returnJson: true
});

var reader = new Ext.data.JsonReader({
    type: 'json',
    totalProperty: 'totalCount',
    rootProperty: 'items',
    successProperty: 'success'
});

var proxy = new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
    reader: reader,
    writer: writer,
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'urlForJson',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
    }
});

Ext.define('Application.store.MyStore', {
    extend  : 'Ext.data.Store',
    storeId : 'MyStore',
    model   : 'Application.model.MyModel',
    autoLoad: false,
    autoSync: true,
    proxy:proxy
});
```

Lets define controller that is going to handle our summary/statistics:

```
Ext.define('Application.controller.SummaryController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    refs: [
        {
            selector: 'summaryPanel',
            ref: 'summaryPanel'
        }
    ],
    init: function () {
        var controller = this;
        controller.listen({
            controller: {
                '*': {
                    addSummary: 'addSummary'
                }
            }
        });
    },

    /**
     * Add summary.
     */
    addSummary: function addSummary(summary) {
        var controller = this;
        var summaryPanel= controller.getSummaryPanel();
        summaryPanel.removeAll();
        Ext.Object.each(stats, function(property, stat){
            var labelFieldName = new Ext.form.Label({
                text: stat.name+': '
            });
            var labelFieldValue = new Ext.form.Label({
                text: stat.value+'  ',
                cls: 'bold-item'
            });
            summaryPanel.items.add(labelFieldName);
            summaryPanel.items.add(labelFieldValue);
        });
        summaryPanel.up('window').doLayout();
    }
});
```

And this is our **SummaryPanel**:

```
Ext.define('Application.view.SummaryPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.summaryPanel',
    xtype: 'summaryPanel',
    layout: 'anchor',
    bodyStyle: 'padding: 5px 5px;',
    items: []
});
```

In next step we are going to load our data to grid and after that we will fill our `SummaryPanel` with statistics/summary:

```
Ext.define('Application.controller.GridController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    init: function () {
        var controller = this;

        controller.control({
            'gridControlPanel': {
                'afterrender': function () {
                    controller.loadStore();
                }
            }
        })
    },
    loadStore: function () {
        var controller = this;
        var store = Ext.getStore('Application.store.MyStore');
        store.load({
            callback: function (records, operation, success) {
                var data = Ext.JSON.decode(operation._response.responseText);

                if (!Ext.isEmpty(data.stats)) {
                    //After loading data, make statistics.
                    controller.fireEvent('addSummary', data.stats);//This event is handled by SummaryController
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And this `UI` that cover all above:

```
Ext.define('Application.view.GridWindow', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias: 'widget.gridWindow',
    xtype: 'gridWindow',
    addMode: false,
    autoShow: true,
    width: 1200,
    height: 700,
    resizable: true,
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'grid',
        store: 'Application.store.MyStore',
        dockedItems: [{
            xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
            dock: 'bottom',
            store: 'Application.store.MyStore',
            displayInfo: true
        }]
    }],
    dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'summaryPanel'//This is our summary panel that will show your summarize.
    }]
});
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the detailed description. But if this code results in a grid similar to `http://i.stack.imgur.com/VVTsQ.png`, my manager won't accept it. I can't understand what's written in it, but it seems to have the summary above the grid. I need the summary looking like a "special row" as in `http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.1/examples/grid/group-summary-grid.html`. I just don't need grouping, and need the values to be provided from server instead of calculated on client side by Ext. If I'd add the summary outside the grid, I'd just add it outside Ext as plain HTML.

Comment: This kind of questions arent trivial and propably wont bring correct answers . This is something that need to be very well implemented and tailored for your needs. I just provided some proof of concept that you can use with your implementation.

Comment: Yes I agree, I'm needing to "merge" multiple examples into one. I'll try your code, I'm first deploying current version to server. Basically what I need is a view like the summary example, without grouping, and feeding the summary data from server because of the paging.

Comment: I understand that `view.getFeature('group').toggleSummaryRow(showSummary);` makes Ext.Grid show the summary, and each column has its `summaryRenderer`attribute to format the summary value. In your example, `"stats"` in json has the summary value. And `SummaryController.addSummary()` takes the stats value and adds it to the summary. What I can't undestand is how you take the SummaryController and hooks it into the grid. I don't need a toolbar to toggle showing the summary, I just need it there.

Comment: To simplify: what code makes Ext.Grid show the summary and what code hooks json's `"stats"` to make summary show its values. I can add `"stats"` to json, if I can do that it will work.

Comment: `controller.fireEvent('addSummary', data.stats);` this part send event to controller `SummaryController` and adds dynamically summary to panel. Its all about events and how they works. Second thing is `refs` in `SummaryController`. When i defined `ref` as `summaryPanel` i can do this in method `addSummary`: `var summaryPanel= controller.getSummaryPanel();` - this is so called hook :)

Comment: lol I'm having trouble to understand your code but I'm advancing. I usually don't use controllers, I hook columns, store and paging directly into a Ext.grid.Panel.

Comment: I still don't get how you hook Application.controller.GridController into the Application.view.GridWindow, and where Application.controller.SummaryController is hooked. I don't need the Application.view.SummaryPanel, it won't be toggled. Also, just to make it clearer, I won't use grouping, I just need a summary at the bottom of the grid.

Comment: I used this example little bit of modified and got it to work on Infinite Grid with Ext JS 4.2.+-

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ExtJS Grid feature -

```
Ext.grid.feature.Summary
```

to display summary at the bottom of grid.

Here is the simple example to answer your question -
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/tq7

In example, i have directly used the `summary` object in `summaryRenderer` of column.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question which was specific to a grid with a paging toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

So, for a summary row, you've got the [Summary feature](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#). You can stick it in the bottom of your grid with the [`dock: 'bottom'`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.grid.feature.Summary-cfg-dock) option. And, finally, to use remotely computed data for the summary, you've got the [`remoteRoot`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.grid.feature.AbstractSummary-cfg-remoteRoot) option. Voilà.

... Except the thing is apparently half baked and `remoteRoot` [is really only used with grouping](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/source/AbstractSummary.html#Ext-grid-feature-AbstractSummary-method-generateSummaryData). Oops. "No need to handle the simple case", they must have thought.

Here's an override that fills the missing part you're needing ([fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ts8)):

```
Ext.define('Ext.grid.feature.RemoteSummary', {
    override: 'Ext.grid.feature.Summary',

    // adds 'remote' summary type
    getSummary: function (store, type, field, group) {
        if (type === 'remote') {
            return this.getRemoteSummaryRecord(store).get(field);
        } else {
            return this.callParent(arguments);
        }
    },

    // helper for our custom summary type, mainly copied from:
    // http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/source/AbstractSummary.html#Ext-grid-feature-AbstractSummary-method-generateSummaryData
    getRemoteSummaryRecord: function(store) {
        if (!this.remoteSummaryRecord) {
            var reader = store.proxy.reader,
                remoteRoot = this.remoteRoot,
                root;

            if (remoteRoot && reader.rawData) {
                root = reader.root;
                reader.root = remoteRoot;
                reader.buildExtractors(true);

                this.remoteSummaryRecord = reader.read(reader.rawData).records[0];

                if (!reader.convertRecordData) {
                    reader.buildExtractors();
                }

                reader.root = root;
                reader.buildExtractors(true);
            }
        }
        if (!this.remoteSummaryRecord) {
            this.remoteSummaryRecord = store.model.create({});
        }
        return this.remoteSummaryRecord;
    },

    // ensure our remoteSummaryRecord stays fresh
    onStoreUpdate: function() {
        delete this.remoteSummaryRecord;
        return this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

You would then use it like this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    features: [{
        ftype: 'summary',
        remoteRoot: 'summary', // summary key in the server response
        dock: 'bottom'
    }],
    columns: [{
        text: 'Age',
        dataIndex: 'age',
        summaryType: 'remote'
    }]
    //...
});
```

With some data of this form:

```
{
    "summary": {
        "age": 95,
    },
    "items": [/*...*/]
}
```

(And, yes, summing ages makes a lot of sense)