# Ext JS 4.2.5 infinite non-grouped summary Grid not work right way on its Java Back-end

Tags: java, extjs, jira, extjs4.2, jira-plugin

I used this example to solve my needs to get Ext JS 4.2.5 infinite non-grouped summary Grid  not work right way on its Java Back-end on latest version of Atlassian Jira Server with no total success:
[Summary + ajax paging on ExtJS.Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32403815/summary-ajax-paging-on-extjs-grid)

[image: Screenshot from Front-end]
[image: Screenshot from Web Developer Tools on Firefox]

And here is the Source Code where is some bug.

```
try
        {
           
           JqlQueryBuilder queryBuilder = JqlQueryBuilder.newBuilder();
           
           JqlQueryBuilder addQueryBuilder = JqlQueryBuilder.newBuilder();
           
           if (issueStatus.equals("--ALL--")) {
           
           if (projectIdreq.equals("--ALL--")) {
           
           if (req.getParameter("fields")==null) {
            
           } else if (req.getParameter("fields").equals("[\"key\"]")) {
               
            if (req.getParameter("query")==null) {
                
            } else if (req.getParameter("query").equals("")) {
                
            } else {
            
            String typeQuery = req.getParameter("query"); 

            }
               
           } else {
            
           }
           
           Query addQuery = addQueryBuilder.buildQuery();
           
           Clause clause = addQuery.getWhereClause();
           
            if (req.getParameter("query")==null) {
                
                if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("ASC")) {
                    queryBuilder.orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.ASC).endOrderBy();
                } else if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("DESC")) {
                        queryBuilder.orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.DESC).endOrderBy();
                    }   
            
            } else if (req.getParameter("query").equals("")) {
                if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("ASC")) {
                    queryBuilder.orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.ASC).endOrderBy();
                } else if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("DESC")) {
            queryBuilder.orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.DESC).endOrderBy();
                }
            
            } else {
                
                if (req.getParameter("fields").equals("[\"key\"]")) {
                    
                String statusQuery = req.getParameter("query");
                if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("ASC")) {
                queryBuilder.where()
                .issue(statusQuery)
                .endWhere()
                .orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.ASC).endOrderBy();
                } else if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("DESC")) {
                    queryBuilder.where().issue(statusQuery)
                .endWhere()
                .orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.DESC).endOrderBy();
                }
                } else if (req.getParameter("fields").equals("[\"summary\"]")) {
                    
                String summaryQuery = req.getParameter("query");
                if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("ASC")) {
                    queryBuilder.where()
                    .summary(summaryQuery)
                .endWhere()
                .orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.ASC).endOrderBy();
                    } else if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("DESC")) {
                queryBuilder.where()
                .summary(summaryQuery)
                .endWhere()
                .orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.DESC).endOrderBy();
                    }
                    
                } else {
                    if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("ASC")) {
                queryBuilder.orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.ASC).endOrderBy();
                    } else if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("DESC")) {
                        queryBuilder.orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.DESC).endOrderBy();
                    }
                }
                
            }
            
           } else {
               
               if (req.getParameter("fields")==null) {
                    
                   } else if (req.getParameter("fields").equals("[\"key\"]")) {
                       
                    if (req.getParameter("query")==null) {
                        
                    } else if (req.getParameter("query").equals("")) {
                        
                    } else {
                    
                    String typeQuery = req.getParameter("query"); 
                    
                    }
                       
                   } else {
                       
                    //addQueryBuilder.where().endWhere();
                    
                   }
                   
                   Query addQuery = addQueryBuilder.buildQuery();
                   
                   Clause clause = addQuery.getWhereClause();
                   
                    if (req.getParameter("query")==null) {
                        
                        if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("ASC")) {
                            queryBuilder.where().project(projectIdreq).endWhere().orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.ASC).endOrderBy();
                        } else if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("DESC")) {
                            queryBuilder.where().project(projectIdreq).endWhere().orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.DESC).endOrderBy();
                        }   
                    
                    } else if (req.getParameter("query").equals("")) {
                        if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("ASC")) {
                            queryBuilder.where().project(projectIdreq).endWhere().orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.ASC).endOrderBy();
                        } else if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("DESC")) {
                            queryBuilder.where().project(projectIdreq).endWhere().orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.DESC).endOrderBy();
                        }
                    
                    } else {
                        
                        if (req.getParameter("fields").equals("[\"key\"]")) {
                            
                        String statusQuery = req.getParameter("query");
                        if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("ASC")) {
                            queryBuilder.where()
                            .issue(statusQuery)
                            .and().project(projectIdreq)
                            .endWhere()
                            .orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.ASC).endOrderBy();
                        } else if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("DESC")) {
                            queryBuilder.where().issue(statusQuery)
                            .and().project(projectIdreq)
                            .endWhere()
                            .orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.DESC).endOrderBy();
                        }
                        } else if (req.getParameter("fields").equals("[\"summary\"]")) {
                            
                        String summaryQuery = req.getParameter("query");
                        if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("ASC")) {
                            queryBuilder.where()
                            .summary(summaryQuery)
                            .and().project(projectIdreq)
                            .endWhere()
                            .orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.ASC).endOrderBy();
                            } else if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("DESC")) {
                                queryBuilder.where()
                                .summary(summaryQuery)
                                .and().project(projectIdreq)
                                .endWhere()
                                .orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.DESC).endOrderBy();    
                            }
                            
                        } else {
                            if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("ASC")) {
                                queryBuilder.where().project(projectIdreq).endWhere().orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.ASC).endOrderBy();
                            } else if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("DESC")) {
                                queryBuilder.where().project(projectIdreq).endWhere().orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.DESC).endOrderBy();
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }
            }
           
           } else if (issueStatus.equals("UNRESOLVED")) {
               
               if (projectIdreq.equals("--ALL--")) {
                   
                   if (req.getParameter("fields")==null) {
                    
                   } else if (req.getParameter("fields").equals("[\"key\"]")) {
                       
                    if (req.getParameter("query")==null) {
                        
                    } else if (req.getParameter("query").equals("")) {
                        
                    } else {
                    
                    String typeQuery = req.getParameter("query"); 
                    
                    }
                       
                   } else {
                    
                   }
                   
                   Query addQuery = addQueryBuilder.buildQuery();
                   
                   Clause clause = addQuery.getWhereClause();
                   
                    if (req.getParameter("query")==null) {
                        
                        if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("ASC")) {
                            queryBuilder.where().and().unresolved().endWhere().orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.ASC).endOrderBy();
                        } else if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("DESC")) {
                                queryBuilder.where().and().unresolved().endWhere().orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.DESC).endOrderBy();
                            }   
                    
                    } else if (req.getParameter("query").equals("")) {
                        if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("ASC")) {
                            queryBuilder.orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.ASC).endOrderBy();
                        } else if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("DESC")) {
                    queryBuilder.orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.DESC).endOrderBy();
                        }
                    
                    } else {
                        
                        if (req.getParameter("fields").equals("[\"key\"]")) {
                            
                        String statusQuery = req.getParameter("query");
                        if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("ASC")) {
                        queryBuilder.where()
                        .issue(statusQuery)
                        .endWhere()
                        .orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.ASC).endOrderBy();
                        } else if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("DESC")) {
                            queryBuilder.where().issue(statusQuery)
                        .endWhere()
                        .orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.DESC).endOrderBy();
                        }
                        } else if (req.getParameter("fields").equals("[\"summary\"]")) {
                            
                        String summaryQuery = req.getParameter("query");
                        if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("ASC")) {
                            queryBuilder.where()
                            .summary(summaryQuery)
                        .endWhere()
                        .orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.ASC).endOrderBy();
                            } else if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("DESC")) {
                        queryBuilder.where()
                        .summary(summaryQuery)
                        .endWhere()
                        .orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.DESC).endOrderBy();
                            }
                            
                        } else {
                            if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("ASC")) {
                        queryBuilder.orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.ASC).endOrderBy();
                            } else if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("DESC")) {
                                queryBuilder.orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.DESC).endOrderBy();
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                   } else {
                       
                       if (req.getParameter("fields")==null) {
                            
                           } else if (req.getParameter("fields").equals("[\"key\"]")) {
                               
                            if (req.getParameter("query")==null) {
                                
                            } else if (req.getParameter("query").equals("")) {
                                
                            } else {
                            
                            String typeQuery = req.getParameter("query"); 
                            
                            }
                               
                           } else {
                            
                           }
                           
                           Query addQuery = addQueryBuilder.buildQuery();
                           
                           Clause clause = addQuery.getWhereClause();
                           
                            if (req.getParameter("query")==null) {
                                
                                if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("ASC")) {
                                    queryBuilder.where().project(projectIdreq).and().unresolved().endWhere().orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.ASC).endOrderBy();
                                } else if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("DESC")) {
                                        queryBuilder.where().project(projectIdreq).and().unresolved().endWhere().orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.DESC).endOrderBy();
                                    }   
                            
                            } else if (req.getParameter("query").equals("")) {
                                if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("ASC")) {
                                    queryBuilder.where().project(projectIdreq).and().unresolved().endWhere().orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.ASC).endOrderBy();
                                } else if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("DESC")) {
                            queryBuilder.where().project(projectIdreq).and().unresolved().endWhere().orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.DESC).endOrderBy();
                                }
                            
                            } else {
                                
                                if (req.getParameter("fields").equals("[\"key\"]")) {
                                    
                                String statusQuery = req.getParameter("query");
                                if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("ASC")) {
                                queryBuilder.where()
                                .issue(statusQuery)
                                .and().project(projectIdreq)
                                .and().unresolved()
                                .endWhere()
                                .orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.ASC).endOrderBy();
                                } else if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("DESC")) {
                                    queryBuilder.where().issue(statusQuery)
                                    .and().project(projectIdreq)
                                    .and().unresolved()
                                .endWhere()
                                .orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.DESC).endOrderBy();
                                }
                                } else if (req.getParameter("fields").equals("[\"summary\"]")) {
                                    
                                String summaryQuery = req.getParameter("query");
                                if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("ASC")) {
                                    queryBuilder.where() //.createdBetween(dateFirstDate, dateLastDate)
                                    .summary(summaryQuery)
                                    .and().project(projectIdreq)
                                    .and().unresolved()
                                .endWhere()
                                .orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.ASC).endOrderBy();
                                    } else if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("DESC")) {
                                queryBuilder.where() //.createdBetween(dateFirstDate, dateLastDate).and()
                                .summary(summaryQuery)
                                .and().project(projectIdreq)
                                .and().unresolved()
                                .endWhere()
                                .orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.DESC).endOrderBy();
                                    }
                                    
                                } else {
                                    if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("ASC")) {
                                        queryBuilder.where().project(projectIdreq).and().unresolved().endWhere().orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.ASC).endOrderBy();
                                    } else if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("DESC")) {
                                        queryBuilder.where().project(projectIdreq).and().unresolved().endWhere().orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.DESC).endOrderBy();
                                    }
                                }
                                
                            }
                    }
               
           } else {
               
               if (projectIdreq.equals("--ALL--")) {
                   
                   if (req.getParameter("fields")==null) {
                    
                   } else if (req.getParameter("fields").equals("[\"key\"]")) {
                       
                    if (req.getParameter("query")==null) {
                        
                    } else if (req.getParameter("query").equals("")) {
                        
                    } else {
                    
                    String typeQuery = req.getParameter("query"); 
                    
                    }
                       
                   } else {
                    
                   }
                   
                   Query addQuery = addQueryBuilder.buildQuery();
                   
                   Clause clause = addQuery.getWhereClause();
                   
                    if (req.getParameter("query")==null) {
                        
                        if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("ASC")) {
                            queryBuilder.where().not().unresolved().endWhere().orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.ASC).endOrderBy();
                        } else if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("DESC")) {
                                queryBuilder.where().not().unresolved().endWhere().orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.DESC).endOrderBy();
                            }   
                    
                    } else if (req.getParameter("query").equals("")) {
                        if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("ASC")) {
                            queryBuilder.where().not().unresolved().endWhere().orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.ASC).endOrderBy();
                        } else if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("DESC")) {
                    queryBuilder.where().not().unresolved().endWhere().orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.DESC).endOrderBy();
                        }
                    
                    } else {
                        
                        if (req.getParameter("fields").equals("[\"key\"]")) {
                            
                        String statusQuery = req.getParameter("query");
                        if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("ASC")) {
                        queryBuilder.where()
                        .issue(statusQuery)
                        .and().not().unresolved()
                        .endWhere()
                        .orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.ASC).endOrderBy();
                        } else if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("DESC")) {
                            queryBuilder.where().issue(statusQuery)
                            .and().not().unresolved()
                        .endWhere()
                        .orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.DESC).endOrderBy();
                        }
                        } else if (req.getParameter("fields").equals("[\"summary\"]")) {
                            
                        String summaryQuery = req.getParameter("query");
                        if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("ASC")) {
                            queryBuilder.where()
                            .summary(summaryQuery)
                            .and().not().unresolved()
                        .endWhere()
                        .orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.ASC).endOrderBy();
                            } else if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("DESC")) {
                        queryBuilder.where() 
                        .summary(summaryQuery)
                        .and().not().unresolved()
                        .endWhere()
                        .orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.DESC).endOrderBy();
                            }
                            
                        } else {
                            if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("ASC")) {
                                queryBuilder.where().and().not().unresolved().endWhere().orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.ASC).endOrderBy();
                            } else if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("DESC")) {
                                queryBuilder.where().and().not().unresolved().endWhere().orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.DESC).endOrderBy();
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                   } else {
                       
                       if (req.getParameter("fields")==null) {
                            
                           } else if (req.getParameter("fields").equals("[\"key\"]")) {
                               
                            if (req.getParameter("query")==null) {
                            
                            } else if (req.getParameter("query").equals("")) {
                                
                            } else {
                            
                            String typeQuery = req.getParameter("query"); 
                               
                            }
                               
                           } else {
                            
                           }
                           
                           Query addQuery = addQueryBuilder.buildQuery();
                           
                           Clause clause = addQuery.getWhereClause();
                           
                            if (req.getParameter("query")==null) {
                           
                                if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("ASC")) {
                                    queryBuilder.where().project(projectIdreq).and().not().unresolved().endWhere().orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.ASC).endOrderBy();
                                } else if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("DESC")) {
                                        queryBuilder.where().project(projectIdreq).and().not().unresolved().endWhere().orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.DESC).endOrderBy();
                                    }   
                            
                            } else if (req.getParameter("query").equals("")) {
                                if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("ASC")) {
                                    queryBuilder.where().project(projectIdreq).and().not().unresolved().endWhere().orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.ASC).endOrderBy();
                                } else if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("DESC")) {
                            queryBuilder.where().project(projectIdreq).and().not().unresolved().endWhere().orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.DESC).endOrderBy();
                                }
                            
                            } else {
                                
                                if (req.getParameter("fields").equals("[\"key\"]")) {
                                    
                                String statusQuery = req.getParameter("query");
                                if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("ASC")) {
                                queryBuilder.where()
                                .issue(statusQuery)
                                .and().project(projectIdreq)
                                .and().not().unresolved()
                                .endWhere()
                                .orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.ASC).endOrderBy();
                                } else if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("DESC")) {
                                    queryBuilder.where().issue(statusQuery)
                                    .and().project(projectIdreq)
                                    .and().not().unresolved()
                                .endWhere()
                                .orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.DESC).endOrderBy();
                                }
                                } else if (req.getParameter("fields").equals("[\"summary\"]")) {
                                    
                                String summaryQuery = req.getParameter("query");
                                if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("ASC")) {
                                    queryBuilder.where() 
                                    .summary(summaryQuery)
                                    .and().project(projectIdreq)
                                    .and().not().unresolved()
                                .endWhere()
                                .orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.ASC).endOrderBy();
                                    } else if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("DESC")) {
                                queryBuilder.where() 
                                .summary(summaryQuery)
                                .and().project(projectIdreq)
                                .and().not().unresolved()
                                .endWhere()
                                .orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.DESC).endOrderBy();
                                    }
                                    
                                } else {
                                    if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("ASC")) {
                                queryBuilder.where().project(projectIdreq).and().not().unresolved().endWhere().orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.ASC).endOrderBy();
                                    } else if (sort.equals("id") && dir.equals("DESC")) {
                                        queryBuilder.where().project(projectIdreq).and().not().unresolved().endWhere().orderBy().issueId(SortOrder.DESC).endOrderBy();
                                    }
                                }
                                
                            }
                    }
               
           } 
               
            Query query = queryBuilder.buildQuery();
            
            SearchResults results = searchService.search(targetUser, query, PagerFilter.getUnlimitedFilter());
            iList = results.getResults();
            pages = results.getTotal();
 
        }
        catch (SearchException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Got an SearchException: " + e.getCause());
        }
        
        Iterator iteratorUnlimited = iList.iterator();
        
        timeSpentTotal = 0;
        doubleTotalOrgEst = 0;
        doubleTotleRemEst = 0;
        doubleTimeSpent = 0;
        
        while (iteratorUnlimited.hasNext()) {
            
            Issue issueIter = (Issue) iteratorUnlimited.next();
            
            try {
            
            if (issueIter.getOriginalEstimate()==null) {
                orgEst = 0.0;
                doubleOrgEst = Double.valueOf(orgEst);
            } else {
                orgEst = Double.valueOf(issueIter.getOriginalEstimate());
                doubleOrgEst = Double.valueOf(orgEst / 3600);
                doubleTotalOrgEst = doubleTotalOrgEst + orgEst;
            }
            
            if (issueIter.getEstimate()==null) {
                remEst = 0.0;
                doubleRemEst = Double.valueOf(remEst);
            } else {
                remEst = Double.valueOf(issueIter.getEstimate());
                doubleRemEst = Double.valueOf(remEst / 3600);
                doubleTotleRemEst = doubleTotleRemEst + remEst;
            }
            
            double timespentInSeconds = 0;
            
            if (issueIter.getTimeSpent()==null) { 
                
            } else {
                timespentInSeconds = Double.valueOf(issueIter.getTimeSpent());
                timeSpentTotal = timeSpentTotal + Double.valueOf(issueIter.getTimeSpent());
            }
            
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            
            timeSpentTotalByDate = 0;
            try {
                remoteObj = new JSONObject()
                    .put("id", pages)
                    .put("timespent", timeSpentTotal / 3600)
                    .put("initial_estimate",doubleTotalOrgEst / 3600)
                    .put("remaining_estimate",doubleTotleRemEst / 3600);
                
           } catch (JSONException err) {
                err.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Got an JSONException: " + err.getCause());
           }
            
            try {
                
                List<GenericValue> worklogs = getTimeSpentsAsList(y,m,1,lastDate,issueIter.getId());
                
                Iterator<GenericValue> worklogIterator = worklogs.iterator();
                
                while (worklogIterator.hasNext()) {
                    
                       GenericValue genericWorklog = worklogIterator.next();
                       
                       Worklog worklog = WorklogUtil.convertToWorklog(genericWorklog, worklogManager, issueManager);
                       Issue issue = issueManager.getIssueObject(genericWorklog.getLong("issue"));
                       
                       Issue iss = worklog.getIssue();

                       startDate = itter.format(worklog.getStartDate());
                       long timeSpent = worklog.getTimeSpent();
                       doubleTimeSpent = Double.valueOf(timeSpent) / 3600;
                               
                       String[] parts = startDate.split("-");
                       int numDays = Integer.valueOf(parts[1]).intValue();
                       
                       if (req.getParameter("fields")==null) {
                           
                           try {
                               
                               obj.put(startDate,getTimeSpentsTotals(y,m,numDays,numDays));
                           
                           } catch (GenericEntityException e) {
                               e.printStackTrace();
                           }
                                
                       if (req.getParameter("query")==null) {
                       
                            try {
                                
                                obj.put(startDate,getTimeSpentsTotals(y,m,numDays,numDays));
                                
                            } catch (GenericEntityException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                       
                       } else if (req.getParameter("query").equals("")) {
                            
                            try {
                                
                                obj.put(startDate,getTimeSpentsTotals(y,m,numDays,numDays));
                                
                            } catch (GenericEntityException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            
                        } else {
                        
                        try {
                
                            obj.put(startDate,getTimeSpentsTotals(y,m,numDays,numDays));
                                                   
                        } catch (GenericEntityException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            
                        }
                        
                        }
                
                   } else {
           
                        try {
                            
                            obj.put(startDate,getTimeSpentsTotals(y,m,numDays,numDays));
                                                   
                        } catch (GenericEntityException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                   
                   }

                }
                
                } catch (GenericEntityException err) {
                    
                }
            
               try
               {
                   double oldTimeSpent = obj.getDouble(startDate);
                   doubleTimeSpent = doubleTimeSpent + oldTimeSpent;
                   JSONObject jsonTimeSpentTotalByDate = new JSONObject().put(startDate, doubleTimeSpent);
                   remoteByDate.put(jsonTimeSpentTotalByDate);
               }
               catch (JSONException e)
               { 
                   
               }
               
            } catch (JSONException jerr) {
                jerr.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Got an JSONException: " + jerr.getCause());
            }
            
        }
        
           }

        }
        else
        {
            //No license (valid or invalid) is stored.
            licenseValid = false;
        }
    
    try {
        merged = new JSONObject(remoteObj, JSONObject.getNames(remoteObj));
        for (int i = 0; i < remoteByDate.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject toMerge = remoteByDate.getJSONObject(i);
            for(String key : JSONObject.getNames(toMerge))
               {
                   merged.put(key, toMerge.get(key));
               }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   
    remote.put(merged);
    issues = arr;
    
    if (licenseValid) {
    
    value = Boolean.valueOf(!"false"
            .equalsIgnoreCase((String) "true"));
         
    try {
    
    json = new JSONObject()
    .put("remotesummary", remote)
    .put("issues", issues)
    .put("totalCount", pages)
    .put("success", value)
    .toString();
    
    } catch (JSONException err) {
        err.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Got an JSONException: " + err.getCause());
    }
    
    } else {
        
        value = Boolean.valueOf(!"false"
            .equalsIgnoreCase((String) "false"));
            
        try {
        
        json = new JSONObject()
        .put("success", value)
        .toString();
        
        } catch (JSONException err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Got an JSONException: " + err.getCause());
        }
    }
    
    resp.setContentType("application/json");        
    resp.getWriter().write(json);
    resp.getWriter().close();
```

So how do I fix the bug? Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right answer for this is that summary is impossible to get work with buffered pagination. So I removed buffered paginated functionality from the LockingGrid and now it works. Also buffered pagination causes multiple issues for other functionalities.